# samsung multiscreen Proguard conflict with exoplayer

Tags: android, proguard, lombok, exoplayer

I want to release my app but in proguard step I face a problem. it Generate some warning when I add [lobmok](https://projectlombok.org) ( or be more specific when I add **samsung-multiscreen** jar file) as follows :

> Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer:
>   can't find referenced class android.media.PlaybackParams
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack: can't find
>   referenced class android.media.PlaybackParams
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$AudioTrackUtil:
>   can't find referenced class android.media.PlaybackParams
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$AudioTrackUtilV23:
>   can't find referenced class android.media.PlaybackParams
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$AudioTrackUtilV23:
>   can't find referenced method 'void
>   setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)' in library class
>   android.media.AudioTrack
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$AudioTrackUtilV23:
>   can't find referenced class android.media.PlaybackParams
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.chunk.VideoFormatSelectorUtil:
>   can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display$Mode getMode()' in
>   library class android.view.Display
>   Warning:com.google.android.exoplayer.chunk.VideoFormatSelectorUtil:
>   can't find referenced class android.view.Display$Mode

When I add following line to *proguard-rules.pro* some of the them disappeared but When I launch to the application it crash.

```
-dontwarn lombok.**
```

Also try this :

```
-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer.** { *; }
```

I think it raise due to conflict between annotation used in exoplayer and **multiscreen** (lombok)

does anyone knows how to fix this issue ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Shajeel the only thing I found is that multiScreen has conflict with progaurd

Comment: Thanks for your replying. Amir is it possible to play YouTube videos using Exo Player and without including YouTube SDK in Android?

Comment: @Shajeel As I remember it's possible, see google/exoplayer demo in github to see what kinds of video it support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue with following **proguard-rule**:

```
-ignorewarnings
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-ignorewarnings

-keep class com.samsung.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-dontwarn com.samsung.multiscreen.BuildConfig
-dontwarn lombok.**
```